# How to include CJuiAutoComplete in a CGridView filter?

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, filtering, yii, jquery-autocomplete

I have a grid view that lists contents of a table, table has column `author_id`.

Now I'm displaying usernames using relation name column syntax `author.username`.

Is it possible to allow user to type in a username in column filter, with support of CJuiAutoComplete, some examples hints?

My code sample:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$model->with('author')->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        // ...
        array(
            'name'=>'author.username',
            'filter'=> // ?
        ),
        // ...
    ),
));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The widget has a 3rd parameter that can be set to true which means that will return a string and will not render the widget CJuiAutoComplete.

```
widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$model->with('author')->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        // ...
        array(
            'name'=>'author.username',
            'filter'=> $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', $array_params, true),

        ),
        // ...
    ),
));
```

and $array_params can be replaced with similar as following ex :

```
          array(
            'name'=>'author_username',
            //'model'=>$model,
            'attribute'=>'city_eve',
            'sourceUrl'=>"/controller/action/",
            'options'=>array(
                'minLength'=>'2',
            ),
            'htmlOptions'=>array(
                'size'=>'36'
            ),
        )
```

and also you have to put in your model search method some checks :

```
if($request->getQuery("author_username")){
            $criteria->addCondition(author.username=:author_username");
            $criteria->params[':author_username'] = $request->getQuery("author_username");
        }
```